# Javascript two equals

Tags: javascript

Trying to deepen my knowledge of JS, can someone tell me what this does/is please?

```
jQuery = $ = this.jQuery;
```

What exactly does two equal signs do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That assigns `this.jQuery` to `$`, and then assigns `$` to `jQuery`.

This works because when assigning a value, it returns the value it just assigned, so another variable can be set to it.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

assigned this.jQuery to $ and jQuery

why not just try it out?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply "stacking" the equals sign as you know it ;)

The example you have could be rewritten to

```
$ = this.jQuery;
jQuery = $;
```

I.e. both variables "jQuery" and "$" is set to the value to the right. (So it saves space and might be more clear that both vars are set to the same value.